# How can I do to keep all images being displayed in same order?

Tags: php, html

My name is Gabriel and for a very long time now I've had this problem in my mind.
I have created a site were you can upload an image to a directory on the server and then the images are displayed on the site. Every image gets its name from the number of images in the folder, so the first image is named "0" and e.g 137 gets "137" as name.

I have also made so that the latest image is displayed first using "array_reverse()".
Here's a snippet of the code using to upload the images:

```
    <?php
    error_reporting(0);

    $files = glob("images/*.*");
    $files = array_reverse($files); 

      for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
      {
      $image = $files[$i];
      echo '<img src="'.$image.'" width="400px" height="300px">';
      }
    ?>
```

To my problem. The order so that the latest images are being display at the top and the oldest at the bottom is working for the first 10 images (remember the first image is called 0).
And then the 11:th and upwards are displayed in another place.

How can I do to change that?
Greatful for any answear.

Comment: You're using lexicographic sorting.  As a string, "11" comes before "2".  You *could* prepend file names with "0" characters, but I imagine a more robust solution would be to track file meta-data in a database.  Each file would correspond to a record in a table, which would include the path for that file.  Sorting the results from a database is much more strongly-typed and can allow you to sort on any number of data values that you collect.

Comment: Do you mean like this? $finalName = "0".$existingFiles.".".$imageExt;

Comment: Why not just write the images to BLOB/bytea (of database) instead!?

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort the array `$files`. [Sorting Arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)

```
sort($files);
```