# Lexicographically order PHP

Tags: php, html

I have created a script that is taking uploaded images and name them after how many images there is in a directory. Like if there is one image in the directory it will be named 0 and the 14:th as 14. I have also created a script that takes the images and displays them on the site with the newest image at the top and oldest at the bottom, using "array_reverse()".

The order is working up to 10 images (remember the first image is 0) but the 11:th image is displayed between 1 and 2 because of the lexicographically order.

How can I prevent this without using a database?

Greatful for any answear!

**EDIT**

Here I've got an example:

```
    <?php
    $title = "Click to see the full size image!";
    //upload from folder
    error_reporting(0);
    $files = glob("images/*.*");
    $files = array_reverse($files);


    for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
    {
    $image = $files[$i];
    echo '<a href="'.$image.'"><img src="'.$image.'" width="400px" height="300px"   title="'.$title.'"></a>';
    }
```

?>

Comment: Didn't you just ask this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21387767/how-can-i-do-to-keep-all-images-being-displayed-in-same-order

Comment: Yes, sorry. You freshed my mined a little so I understood it better, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are talking about "Natural Ordering" or natural sorting. This comes built in with php. Check out this example (which happens to deal with image names!)

http://php.net/natsort

```
<?php
    $title = "Click to see the full size image!";
    //upload from folder
    error_reporting(0);
    $files = glob("images/*.*");
    natsort($files);


    for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
    {
    $image = $files[$i];
    echo '<a href="'.$image.'"><img src="'.$image.'" width="400px" height="300px"   title="'.$title.'"></a>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Definitely better than my `SORT_NUMERIC` attempt. :) +1 Found this article: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order.html

Comment: @user3241632 see edits. I think this is what you want. it will sort your images/ folder naturally and print them out in order.

Comment: Thank you, but the natsort() is not highlighted as the other functions for me, what can this depend on?

Comment: you are using some sort of IDE? Are you using php 4/5?

Comment: Sorry for late answear, my PHP version is 5.5.6.

Comment: I think the "natsort()" is working but my program (notepad++) just doesn't highlight it like the other functions.

Comment: try following this: http://g-liu.com/blog/2013/08/updating-the-php-syntax-highlighter-in-notepad/

Comment: Ok, thanks for taking your time asisting me! I think I've got the answears I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [natsort](https://www.php.net/natsort) command for this, which applies a [natural ordering](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order.html) to the items in your list.

For example:

```
<?php
  $array1 = $array2 = array("img12.png", "img10.png", "img2.png", "img1.png");
  natsort($array2);
  print_r($array2);
?>
```

gives:

```
Array
(
    [3] => img1.png
    [2] => img2.png
    [1] => img10.png
    [0] => img12.png
)
```